# Traveling with a back to back Schengen Visa

Tags: visas, schengen

I have two Schengen visas

- one from Spain: valid until 05/19/2017
- one from France: valid from 05/20/2017 until 11/19/2017

I am traveling Friday, 05/12/2017 to Spain for two days then flying to France for two weeks.

Do you think I will run into issues because I have a back to back visas?